# How to use environment variables in a powershell pipeline?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, environment-variables, pipelining

The command

```
systeminfo | find "System Type"
```

is supposed to return

```
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

both in a Command Prompt window and in PowerShell.

In my case it says

```
/usr/bin/find: 'System Type': No such file or directory
```

because, as it was explained to me on https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/1025, I have another `find` in [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which is on my path.

What works correctly in this case is

```
systeminfo | c:\windows\system32\find.exe "System Type"
```

Now suppose I want to make it independent from where the system resides (say, if I want to include this command in some guide for careless users or alike). I thought about invoking instead

```
systeminfo | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "System Type"
```

This works in a Command Prompt but not in PowerShell. In the latter, I have tried

```
systeminfo | $env:SystemRoot\system32\find.exe "System Type"
```

but this gives the error

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
```

I also get an error if I do full path but without `.exe`:  this

```
systeminfo | c:\windows\system32\find "System Type"
```

gives

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: C:\windows\system32\find
```

I also tried

```
systeminfo | % $env:SystemRoot\system32\find.exe "System Type"
```

but this produces an avalanche of errors like

```
% : Input name "C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe" cannot be resolved to a method.
```

What is going on? How to do it properly?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but the PowerShell way for what you want to achieve would be: `systeminfo | sls 'System Type'`

Comment: FYI... Keep in mind how PowerShell handles things, aka [about_Command_Precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7), and how one needs to set things up for running 3rdP executables or executables in general. aka [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
systeminfo | & $env:SystemRoot\system32\find.exe "System Type"
```

note the ampersand before the command.

But ever better, use native PowerShell rather than pipe non-PowerShell output to non-PowerShell programs.

```
(Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsSystemType).CsSystemType
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I actually prefer the first version since it works in much more generality.

Comment: Do you by chance know why does not it work without `.exe`?

Comment: `systeminfo | & $env:SystemRoot\system32\find "System Type"` works for me.

Comment: That's strange. But I made mistake about the error message, will correct, it is not the same, it is different.